# Is it possible to precompile LambdaExpression at project compile time?

Tags: c#, lambda

In my code I define LambaExpression like this:

```
Expression<Func<object>> exp = () => myObject.Property;
```

And I need to compile it into Func, so I do this:

```
Func<object> compiled = exp.Compile();
```

Since the expression is defined at compile time, the compiler could theoretically precompile the expression.

Is it possible to precompile LambdaExpression if the expression is defined in code (not constructed at runtime)?

I know the compile can't perform exp.Compile() at compile time, but for given code 'Expression<Func exp => ()=> myObj.Property' it could generate `Func<object> compileExp = () => myObj.Property`.

---

##### A more concrete example

Any scenario, when you need to point to a class member in code in order to get some metadata (Name, Attributes, etc.) and get its value.

```
// Slow because of runtime compilation
var param1 = new FormField(() => myObj.Property1); 

// Verbose and prone to errors due DRY violation 
var param2 = new FormField(() => myObj.Property1, () => myObj.Property1);

Console.WriteLine($"{param1.MemberName}: {param1.Value}")

class FormField
{
    public FormField(
       Expression<Func<object>> propertyExpression, 
       Func<object>? accessor = null)
    {
        MemberName = ((MemberExpression)propertyExpression.Body).Member.Name;
        Accessor = accessor ?? propertyExpression.Compile();
    }
    public string MemberName {get; }
    public Func<object> Accessor {get; }

    public object Value => Accessor();
}
```

What I expect is that the compiler would generate the `accessor` parameter, e.g., when defined like this:

```
public FormField(
    Expression<Func<object>> propertyExpression, 
    [CallerArgumentExpression("propertyExpression")] Func<object>? accessor = null)
```

Or it would simply cache it internally, so `propertyExpression.Compile()` would return the cached function.

Comment: What would you expect from this kind pf pre-compilation? You're passing your expressions at *runtime*, so how would you imagine the compiler to do anything here? Btw.: in your code you're asking "can this be done at **runtime**". So what exactly are you after here?

Comment: In general case `myObject`/`myObj` would be created and runtime and would be closed over (see the lambda closures), so no, you can't precompile it.

Comment: Erm, just use a normal lambda? `Func<object> compiled = () => myObject.Property;` If the compiler knew what the expression did at compile time then you wouldn't need an expression in the first place.

Comment: Your question makes no sense: either you know the delegate at compile-time, or you don't. In the first case you won't need any expression at all,you already *have* a delegate at **compile-time**. In the other case use an `Expression` and call it's `Compile`-function to build the delegate at **runtime**. Seems like you're just confused about the fact that `Compile` has nothing to do with the compiler, it's just a function that creates delegates.

Comment: I need both, Expression (in order to get MemberInfo) and Func. This is very common for UI components (e.g. a grid's column definition). I just hoped that if the Expression is declared in code, the C# compiler could be clever enough to precompile it. Currently I either declare both Expression and Func in code, or compile Func at runtime, which is too slow.

Comment: @GuruStron: I believe that lambda closures doesn't make precompilation impossible. The closure class (not sure what the right naming is) can be generated by the compiler because `myObject` type is known at compile time. `myObject`  instance is just passed to the closure class instance.
Anyway, even if I had to rewrite the labmda without closure, the question remains

Comment: @Charlieface: _"Erm, just use a normal lambda"_ : You mean `Func<>`? Well I need the expression as well, see the MemberName in "More concrete example"

Comment: @Liero _"because myObject type is known at compile time"_ - compiler can't even create constant fields of reference types =)

Comment: This question is basically "how can I perform an implicitly run-time operation at compile time" which should demonstrate how nonsensical it it.

Comment: @IanKemp: no, that is not the question. Actually razor compiler does something very similar, but reversed. for `@bind-Value="someObj.Value` it creates LambdaExpression, getter and setter functions, although it is code generation rather than compilation

Comment: "razor compiler does something very similar, but reversed" so _not the same thing at all_ then.

Comment: Ok, the example was misleading. the compiler magic shouldn't happen inside FormField ctor, but when calling it, see the edit

Comment: Sounds like you need to write a [Roslyn Source Generator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to precompile LambdaExpression at project compile time?

No. The compiler does not and cannot know the exact type of the object being referred to by the lambda, because that is and can only be resolved at runtime.

> I know the compile can't perform exp.Compile() at compile time, but for given code 'Expression<Func exp => ()=> myObj.Property' it could generate Func compileExp = () => myObj.Property.

Why would you expect that?

> What I expect is that the compiler would generate the accessor parameter

Why would you expect that?

> or it [the compiler] would simply cache it internally

Cache it *where*? With the fairies?

Comment: _"Cache it where?"_ `exp.__compiledDelegateCache = new Func<object>(() => myObj.Property)`